# using spinner to converter

Tags: java, android, spinner, converters

I'm creating converter (distance) 4 Android. My idea was do it like:

1. EditText - user put value f.e. 40
2. two Spinners - first to set started unit and second to set destination unit f.e. first [cm] second [meters]
3. TextView with result
4. Button to calculating

I did functions with calculating values, the problem is how to choose units
this is my code which didn't work

```
spinnerP = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerPocz);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapterP = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.odlegloscArray, R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    adapterP.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinnerP.setAdapter(adapterP);

    spinnerP.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), parent.getItemIdAtPosition(position) + " selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });

    spinnerD = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerDoc);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapterD = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.odlegloscArray, R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    adapterD.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinnerD.setAdapter(adapterD);

    spinnerD.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            if (spinnerP.getItemAtPosition(position) == 0) {
                switch (position) {
                    case 0:
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "zmień wartość docelową", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); //units the same
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        btnOblicz.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                metryNaKm(); //meters to km
                            }
                        });
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        btnOblicz.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                metryNaCm(); //meters to cm
                            }
                        });
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        btnOblicz.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                metryNaCale(); //meters to inch
                            }
                        });
                        break;
//etc.
//then there is
else if (spinnerP.getItemAtPosition(position) == 1) {
                switch (position) {
                    case 0:
                        btnOblicz.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                kilometryNaM(); //km to meters
//etc
```

I guess that doing it like this is horrible, but I'mma not advanced, I am open to suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you should do is to remove all your OnItemselectedListeners, and use only one OnClickListener for your button. Then use getSelectedItemPosition.

```
btnOblicz.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

          int selectedP = spinnerP.getSelectedItemPosition();
          int selectedD = spinnerD.getSelectedItemPosition();        

          switch(selectedP){
             case 0:
                  switch(selectedD){
                       case 1:
                            convertFrom0to1();
                            break;
                       case 2:
                            convertFrom0to2();
                       ....
                   }
                   break;
            ....
           }
    }
});
```